# Changed integer value doesn't show up in other parts of the code?

Tags: java, if-statement, int

I'm sorry for the weird title, I didn't really know how to describe it. Basically I have a code that once the if statement is called, it changed the value of the integer, *taxrate*. I thought it was working, but once I try to call it into a JTextField in another part of the code, it shows up as 0. The IF statement is the following:

```
if (taxable >= 1 && taxable <= 9075){
        taxrate = (int) (taxable * .10);
    } else if (taxable >= 9076 && taxable <= 36900) {
        taxrate = (int) (taxable * .15 + 908);
    } else if (taxable >= 36901 && taxable <= 89350) {
        taxrate = (int) (taxable * .25 + 5082);
    } else if (taxable >= 89351 && taxable <= 186350){
        taxrate = (int) (taxable * .28 + 18195);
    } else if (taxable >= 186351 && taxable <= 405100){
        taxrate = (int) (taxable * .33 + 45355);
    } else if (taxable >= 405101 && taxable <= 406750) {
        taxrate = (int) (taxable * .35 + 45883);
    } else if (taxable >= 406751) {
        taxrate = (int) (taxable * .396);
    }
```

*taxable* is defined by the user, it has no defined value until the user inputs it.

Comment: Well, for one thing, an integer has no decimals.

Comment: Possible. 0 is less then 9075, and 0 * 0.10 is still 0 (and with your cast, any number >= 0 and <= 9 will yield a taxrate of 0).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch It happens even if I enter 9074 for the input

Comment: @engz And if you enter 9076?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I was just showing part of the code, I included the full if statement. I also made a slight edit to be above/equal to 1.

Comment: Add a print before your if(s). Also, where did you get those constants for the addition?

Comment: I would recommend debugging it, or using a println(taxrate); in various spots because I just thoroughly tested the code. I don't think it is an error with this IF statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any value of taxable between 0 and 10 (excluding 10) will give you a taxrate of 0 with the code working flawlessly.
If this is not your case, please make sure that your taxable value is actually assigned before this comparison is made. It is possible that the program is never actually getting to the code block inside the if statement.

Comment: Yeah, I just found my error. It was misplaced. Thank you for pointing that out to me, a silly mistake. :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to clear up your code

```
if (taxable >= 1 && taxable <= 9075){
    taxrate =  (taxable * .10);
} else if (taxable >= 9076 && taxable <= 36900) {
    taxrate =  (taxable * .15 + 908);
} else if (taxable >= 36901 && taxable <= 89350) {
    taxrate =  (taxable * .25 + 5082);
} else if (taxable >= 89351 && taxable <= 186350){
    taxrate =  (taxable * .28 + 18195);
} else if (taxable >= 186351 && taxable <= 405100){
    taxrate =  (taxable * .33 + 45355);
} else if (taxable >= 405101 && taxable <= 406750) {
    taxrate =  (taxable * .35 + 45883);
} else if (taxable >= 406751) {
    taxrate =  (taxable * .396);
}
```

What is the point of having decimals if you cast them to an INT ? Integers can not have decimal places. If you want to have Decimals use Double - otherwise just dont use decimals.

Also make sure that `taxable` is initialized before the if block is executed
i.e.

```
private double taxable = "some value";
```